# Community user fixes grammar now?

Tags: support, community-user

Has the Community user become self aware? Do we need to pull the plug now, before it starts self replicating and decides to take over humanity?

Ok, more seriously, I just noticed that the Community user has fixed some grammar on an answer on aviation:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/3375/revisions

[image]

Is this a new feature? What is it's scope? How does it decide to do this?

I've been using stackexchange sites for a long while, and I've never seen this before

Comment: Damnit, I even searched before asking this. Thanks @animuson

Answer (score 5):

It was an [approved edit by an anonymous user](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1554). If these get approved, the post will get edited by Community♦.